# How to view HTML on terminal using Nokogiri on Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, ubuntu, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse the HTML page of wikipedia using Nokogiri on Ruby(2.5.1) on Ubuntu, here is my code and what my terminal says back:

Any ideas on where the problem comes from ? I tried bundle install just before but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for any help brought !

````
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://en.wikipedia.org'))   
puts page   # => Nokogiri::HTML::Document```



```asus@asus-X75VD:~/THP/jour8/lib$ ruby test8.rb 
Nokogiri::HTML::Document```
````

Comment: What is the problem? The code does exactly what it should according to how you wrote it (print the class of the `page` object), so we can't get a hint from that. What did you want to happen instead? `puts page.to_xml`?

Comment: Sorry @Amadan I edited the last version of my ruby page, and it still does the same. Isn't it supposed to print the whole html page of the website required ?

Comment: Your code, as it is now, does print the whole html page of the website, at least on my system. Are you sure your code is as posted? If it is, what version of nokogiri does `gem list nokogiri` report?

Comment: But all I see is this "Nokogiri::HTML::Document" on my terminal, am I missing something here ?

Comment: My colleagues here don't have the same problem (Mac OS), only one of them has the same problem and he runs on Ubuntu as well. ```gem list nokogiri``` reports ```*** LOCAL GEMS ***

nokogiri (1.10.2)
```

Comment: I tried your code on ubundu 18.4 LTS, it prints the html document of the page

Comment: Wikipedia has an API. I'd recommend using it rather than scraping pages. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, Nokogiri has a command-line equivalent that lets you retrieve a page and play with it in IRB so you don't have to mess with writing code until you're ready to. If you enter:

```
nokogiri https://en.wikipedia.org
```

at the terminal prompt you'll drop into IRB and be able to do something like:

```
irb(main):002:0> @doc.to_s[0..10]
=> "<!DOCTYPE h"
```

or:

```
irb(main):005:0> @doc.to_s.size
=> 76139
```

You can view the page, write it to disk, all the normal things.